# Set range before "with range.delete endwith" fails

Tags: vba, excel

If I Set range before the With, after that, rng_dest has lost the defined range.
But if I set the range after the with, it works ok.
Do you know why? Thanks!!

```
Set rng_dest = Sheets("AO_Interlocks").Range("A2")
With Sheets("AO_Interlocks")
    Range(.Range("A2"), .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).EntireRow.Delete  
End With
```

Comment: In your code you set `rng_dest` but then you delete the range it is set to so it loses its definition

Comment: Yes. I set rng_dest to point to a particular cell. Then I delete all used rows in that sheet (clean its content) but I still wanna have rng_dest to be pointing to A2. It's no problem because I can set rng_dest after clean the sheet, but wonder why it doesn't works if I do the "set" before the "with"

Comment: Because you've just deleted it - You've got rid of the reference it is set to. If I told you to turn left at the traffic lights, and then removed the traffic lights before you got there, should I expect you to know where to go? It's the same

Comment: @e270889o - That's how it works, as @Tom said . Alternatively you can use `Range(.Range("A2"), .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).EntireRow.ClearContents` if deleting is not really necessary. Then `rng_dest` will still point to `Range("A2")`.

Comment: @Mrig you could even use `.Clear` as this would get rid of formatting as well.

Comment: I thought entirerow.delete only cleans the row so range would be still pointing at A2. So what you say is that entirerow.delete it's like right click into the row and then delete the row so no row A exist anymore (even if after that row B renames to A). Right?

Comment: Exactly, now you got what @Tom is saying.

Comment: The ClearContents its the key. I think I have misinterpreted .Delete for .ClearContents.  Thanks both of you!

Comment: I think you can post an answer and I can marked. I cannot find a way to mark your comments as valid answers. Im so noob xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a range to a `rng_dest` using `Set rng_dest = Sheets("AO_Interlocks").Range("A2")` and then deletes `Range("A2")` then it also voids the reference of `rng_dest` to the range assigned.

Alternatively, if deleting range is not necessary you can use

```
Range(.Range("A2"), .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).EntireRow.ClearContents
```

instead of

```
Range(.Range("A2"), .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).EntireRow.Delete
```

or even `Range(.Range("A2"), .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).EntireRow.Clear` will work as mentioned by @Tom in comments, depending on your requirement.